# touchmoved not working after displaying uiimageviews from NSMutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsmutablearray, touchesbegan

I am developing a project in which I have created a `UIImageView` dynamically using an `NSMutableArray`

The code for this is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < index ; i++) {
    image_name= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%dpng.png",[string_values objectAtIndex:0],i+1];

    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image_name]];

    tempImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    CGSize size2=tempImageView.image.size;
    int width2=size2.width/2;
    int height2 =size2.height/2;
    tempImageView.frame = CGRectMake(xvalue,yvalue,width2,height2);  

    [myArray addObject:tempImageView];
}
```

After that I add the subview to show it on the screen with this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<[myArray count];i++) {
    [self.view addSubview:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

All the above code runs well as according to the needs. Now for the touchesBegan method, I am doing this code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    printf("the touch is fired");
    for(int i=0;i<[myArray count];i++) {
        [self.view addSubview:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

The app crashes when the `touchesBegan` method is called, right after it prints the first line of the touchesBegan method.

I am having difficulties here and have also gone through many question/answers but can't find a working solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for Good Replies

Comment: declare myArray as strong and at the time of initialization, use self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: It is not clear What are you doing in the touchesbegan function?

Comment: Can you tell what you want to do in touchesBegan method @Tahir Mehmood

Comment: @Vinu1991 actually after drawing the images >> i want to drag them all of them are working well with only one image and when i added 5 images through NSMutable array then the app is crashing in touchesBegan method actually the getting coordinates and comparison is done in touchesMoved and touchesEnded method>> but the app crashes before going to them

Comment: @samfisher where to put the self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array]; ???

Comment: @TahirMehmood - before the for loop where you are adding all uiimageviews to the array

Answer (score 0):

To make your imageviews draggable,

1) Remove all - (void)touches methods

2) Add these two lines just after creating UIImageView *tempImageView (in loop)

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDrag:)];
[tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

3) then, add this method somewhere in your view controller.m file

```
-(void) handleDrag:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) panGesture{
CGPoint transition = [panGesture translationInView:self.view];
panGesture.view.center = CGPointMake(panGesture.view.center.x + transition.x, panGesture.view.center.y +transition.y);
[panGesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];}
```

Comment: i am using touchesBegan ,touchesMoved,touchesEnded methods>> and any suggestion using that methods???

Comment: My advice is not to use touchesBegan ,touchesMoved,touchesEnded in your code for dragging imageviews. Using GestureRecognizers makes your code very clear and it is the recommended way.

Comment: then how to retreive the touch coordinates >> where the user touches the uiimageview>>

Comment: Could you please clearly tell me what you want to do ? I can help you

Comment: i am developing a game in which i am displaying five uiimageviews randomly on screen>> i use uiimageview arrays to store and then through iteration to whole array i am adding the subviews>> the problem is taht after drawing the images the touch function is not executed>> actually the touchesBegan function takes a uiimage to identified the drag for each element> but in my case i use the uiimage array so what to give to touch function to executes>> its all working good for an individual image ???